# How to access navigation prop in tabs navigation - react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I need to put a floating button appears in all screens, i put it in bottom tab navigator with absolute position but i couldn't set the onPress navigation for it.. how can i access navigation.navigate in tab navigator?

my code

```
MoreStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'More',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, navigation }) => (
    <View>
      <TabBarIcon
        focused={focused}
        name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-more' : 'md-more'}
        type='ionicon'
      />
       <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 20,
            alignItems: 'center',
            right: 10,
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat')}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/chat.png')}
              style={{ alignSelf: 'center', height: 60, width: 60 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  ),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To able to navigate anywhere, keep a reference of the `NavigationContainer`.

Example: i created a `NavigationService` like the following:

```
import { CommonActions, StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";// react navigation 5
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation"; // react navigation 4

export default class NavigationService {
    // core navigator
    private static navigator;

    // sets the core navigator
    static setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
        NavigationService.navigator = navigatorRef;
    }
    // naviget to a route
    static navigate(name, params?) {
        NavigationService.navigator.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({ name, params }));
    }

    static goBack() {
        return NavigationService.navigator.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack());
    }

    static popToTop() {
        NavigationService.navigator.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())
    }
}
```

And in your App.js:

```
<NavigationContainer ref={(ref) => NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(ref)}>
// 
</NavigationContainer>
```

Now the `NavigationService` has a reference of the `NavigationContainer`, thus you can navigate anywhere by doing:

```
NavigationService.navigate("SomeScreen");
```

If you are using react navigation 4 replace `CommonActions` with `NavigationActions`.