# How to access the navigation prop in the Stack Navigator's screenOptions attribute?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to navigate to a particular screen using a common header button in the stack navigator.

```
 <NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator 
    mode="modal"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTitle: () => <SpreeLogo />,
      headerRight: (props) => <MaterialIcons style={{
        marginHorizontal: 10,
      }}
      onPress={() => console.log(props)}
      name="clear" size={28} color="black" />
    }}
  >
```

In the header right icon I would like to have access to the navigation prop. I've tried console logging the prop but there is no prop as navigation. How to get access to it?

Comment: i usually keep a reference of the navigator, that way i can navigate from wherever i am,, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865226/how-to-access-navigation-prop-in-tabs-navigation-react-navigation/62873252#62873252

Answer (score 9):

As per documentation you can provide a function to screenOptions like below which will give you access to the navigation and from there you should be able to jump to any screen

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator 
    mode="modal"
    screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTitle: () => <SpreeLogo />,
      headerRight: (props) => <MaterialIcons style={{
        marginHorizontal: 10,
      }}
      onPress={() => console.log(route, navigation)}
      name="clear" size={28} color="black" />
    })}
  >...
```

Read the docs here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator and search for screenOptions.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

In React Navigation V6 you can provide a function to options

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Screen"
    component={Screen}
    options={({ route, navigation }) => ({
      headerTitleAlign: "center",
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon
          name="arrow-back"
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          color="#fff"
          size={25}
        />
      ),

    })}
  />
```

Comment: This is a working example in a Stack.Screen but @vivek-mahajan is asking for a RootStack.Navigator

Answer (score 0):

### The useNavigation hook

In a root navigator the Navigation prop may be accessed with the `useNavigation` hook documented [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) in the v6.x React Navigation Documentation.

> useNavigation is a hook which gives access to navigation object. It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.
>
> useNavigation() returns the navigation prop of the screen it's inside.

Example from React Navigation docs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Example using OP code:

```
export function MyScreen() {

//Hook to access the navigation prop of the parent screen anywhere.
// @returns — Navigation prop of the parent screen.
const navigation = useNavigation();

 return(
 <NavigationContainer>
  <RootStack.Navigator 
    mode="modal"
    screenOptions={{
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTitle: () => <SpreeLogo />,
      headerRight: (props) => <MaterialIcons style={{
        marginHorizontal: 10,
      }}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Somewhere') }
      name="clear" size={28} color="black" />
    }}
 )
}
```